# OpenAPI, SpringBoot 3.x not eveerything uses Jakarta instead of Javax

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator, jakarta-migration

I am trying to bump up dependencies in my project to SpringBoot 3.x. As Spring is switching from javax to jakarta, I'm trying to make it all happened in the project as well.
I'm, using OpenAPI to generate some files, and as for most of them everything works as expected, the problem is with ApiUtils - it is still trying to us javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.

I have checked mustache files and there is no javax dependency there.
Any ideas how to deal with that? I would appreciate any help.

Parts of my pom connected to the issue:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <jakarta.servlet-api.version>6.0.0</jakarta.servlet-api.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version>2.0.2</springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version>
    </properties>

 <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-databind-nullable.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct.extensions.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-spring-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct-spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct.extensions.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-spring-extensions</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct-spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakarta.servlet-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-starter-activemq.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Spring dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a [known issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/14276) that was actually just fixed yesterday with [this merge](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/commit/456cca1a28b1791d63ab19dfd04addb52d1414f4#diff-1102153d5430cf951b942643dd3ae5d8c7d3a1d973067cca9c682e7c4efa3cfd).  Now, you can use the new `useJakartaEe` config option to force the Jakarta imports.

#### *Maven Example*

```xml
<configOptions>
  <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
</configOptions>
```

#### *Gradle Example*

```
configOptions = [
  useJakartaEe: "true"
]
```

#### *CLI Example*

```
openapi-generator -g spring -o out -i spec.yaml --additional-properties=useJakartaEe=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `kotlin-spring` generator the fix is to add this configuration option:

```
    "useSpringBoot3": "true"
```

Which according to the documentation:

> Generate code and provide dependencies for use with Spring Boot 3.x. (Use jakarta instead of javax in imports). Enabling this option will also enable useJakartaEe.

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/kotlin-spring.md